# Ошибка в массиве

Tags: c#

Скажите пожалуйста, что делаю неправильно.
Есть код:

```
double[,] matrix = new double[3,3];
        try
        {
            matrix[0, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1);
            matrix[0, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2);
            matrix[0, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3);
            matrix[1, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4);
            matrix[1, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5);
            matrix[1, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6);
            matrix[2, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox7);
            matrix[2, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8);
            matrix[2, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox9);
        }
        catch
        {
            label12.Text = "Ошибка";
        }

        label3.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[0, 0]);
        label4.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[0, 1]);
        label5.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[0, 2]);
        label6.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[1, 0]);
        label7.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[1, 1]);
        label8.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[1, 2]);
        label9.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[2, 0]);
        label10.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[2, 1]);
        label11.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[2, 2]);
```

Но вот получается, что даже когда нет ошибок (т.е. все значения введены в форму), то элементы массива равны 0.

Comment: Может должно быть:  

     textbox.text
     textbox.value

Или вроде того.

Comment: Угу. `textBox1.Text`.

А вообще, ваш код слишком прямолинее[н](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#K.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B9.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4), попробуйте отказаться от генерирования контролов через дизайнер форм, и воспользуйтесь хотя бы массивом.

Comment: @VladD, условие задания превыше всего )
Но при исправлении  "textBox1.Text." частично помогло.
Теперь если вводить матрицу 
1 _ 1
1 _ _
_ _ _ 
получится что-то типа
1 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0.
Т.е. если предыдущий элемент не указан, то число не внесет в массив, а "занулит" его.

Comment: @wao138: Ну, а что ж вы хотели? `_` — это ж не число. А вы его конвертируете в число.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправьте следующим образом и все будет работать
double[,] matrix = new double[3,3];
        try
        {
            matrix[0, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            matrix[0, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            matrix[0, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            matrix[1, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            matrix[1, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
            matrix[1, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
            matrix[2, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text);
            matrix[2, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text);
            matrix[2, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox9.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            label12.Text = "Ошибка";
        }

```
    label3.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[0, 0]);
    label4.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[0, 1]);
    label5.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[0, 2]);
    label6.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[1, 0]);
    label7.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[1, 1]);
    label8.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[1, 2]);
    label9.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[2, 0]);
    label10.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[2, 1]);
    label11.Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[2, 2]);
```